# why showing Fatal Error on static function

Tags: php

I have a tiny class of inserting payment record into database. below is given:

```
<?php

class pay{
        public static function pay($user, $income, $type, $refid='--'){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO earn VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$income', '$refid', '$type', ".time().")");   
        }
    }

?>
```

But browser gives the below fatal error..

> Fatal error: Constructor pay::pay() cannot be static in F:\xampp\htdocs\new\sts\class.php on line 41

I am confused that why the error occurring.. please help me to understand.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have a method name that is the same as the name of the class, it is considered to be a constructor.  Constructors cannot be static.  You must either rename this class or method, or make the method *not* static and create an instance of the class when you want to use it.

Answer (score 10):

In PHP 5, constructors are called `__construct`. In PHP 4 it used to be the name of the class, e.g. `function pay` for `class pay`. PHP 5 is backwards compatible with PHP 4, so that still works. Constructors cannot be `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor's are called on the creation of an object, and thus can not be static. By naming a function the same as the class, php thinks you want that to be the constructor

Answer (score 1):

A method whose name is the same as that of the class it's defined on isn't an ordinary method but a constructor, used for making new instances of the class. Constructors are not allowed to be static, because the whole point of them is to act on a newly created class instance.