# Error: Non-static method cannot be called statically

Tags: php, parsing, mediawiki

I'm very new to using PHP and am trying to update an extension for a wiki I'm working on. I've somehow managed to bumble through updating most of it to run correctly, but currently I'm having problems with it returning "Error: Non-static method URLFormat::urlformat() cannot be called statically".

I tried to do some reading on how to fix this issue, but I got kind of lost on how to do so with my specific usecase.  I tried swapping the "public static function" to just be "public function" with no luck, so I've just put the original code generating the error here. One of the engines I used to check my code offered that I should be using __construct, but that honestly just made me more confused.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<?php

class URLFormat {

    public static function urlformat( &$parser ) {
        $parser->setHook( 'urlformat', __CLASS__.'::parserHook' );
        return true;
    }
     public static function parserHook( $parser ) {
        global $wgURLFormat;

        // Validate title
        if ( $text === '' ) {
            global $wgTitle;
            if ( !is_object( $wgTitle ) ) return "NO TITLE OBJECT";
            $text = $wgTitle->getPrefixedText();
        }

        // Convert all white space to spaces, remove (toon) at the end of a title,
        // convert all to lowercase, remove all nonalphanumeric/nonspace characters,
        // and then replace all remaining spaces with hyphens
        $text = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', trim( $text ) );
        $text = preg_replace( '/ \(toon\)$/', '', $text );
        $text = strtolower( $text );
        $text = preg_replace( '/[^\w ]/', '', $text );
        $text = preg_replace( '/[ _]+/', '-', $text );

    return $text;
    }
}
```

---

Attempted: Creation of a custom parserhook for use in MediaWiki.

Expected behavior: Website should load up fine. Upon editing, pages should allow for the use of {{#urlformat}} to generate the ending of a URL based on certain text.

Actual behavior: Website currently loads with the following error message and backtrace: https://pastebin.com/4EWuzw4p

**Update:** The naming of my function as URLFormat::urlformat was causing the program to read it as being a construct. Changing it to URLFormat::format fixed the issue. Sourced from here: [why showing Fatal Error on static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421396/why-showing-fatal-error-on-static-function)

Comment: `URLFormat::urlformat()` is static in your question, perhaps this error is for a different class definition?

Comment: Hm. I re-ran it after playing around with the different names and it still turned the same error. I wonder if part of the problem is in the json file?
Update: something definitely seems to be up with the class definition, but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Read the error message. Understand it. Don't guess longer than five minutes. Read that error message word by word, look up the meaning of each word from reference documentation and learn. Otherwise you can run up and down and play the guess game but that's not helpful. And out of topic for SO.